# Copying an AWS Elastic Beanstalk development instance over to the existing production instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, pycharm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

What is the recommended way to copy the code of a development instance over to the production instance.

I currently have two AWS EB instances called xxx-dev and xxx-production. I want to move my code over from the xxx-dev instance to the xxx-production instance. Should this be done using an eb deploy from my local git? Or is there a way to simply use the AWS dashboard to do this.

Clearly this a newbie question but I have been unable to find a suitable document online that describes this although I am sure such a document must exist?

To give a fuller picture:

1. I have two EB instances xxx-dev and xxx-production
2. I inherited the production instance so have as yet never updated it
3. I use PyCharm on my Mac to develop the development code which is deployed from time to time to the xxx-dev instance
4. Both xxx-dev and xxx-production use an RDS database
5. I am now at the stage where I want to update xxx-production with the current state of the code as is currently running on the xxx-dev instance
6. I can't see a simple way to do this via PyCharm

Any suggestions would be gratefully received. As I say I am sure there must be a document on this but have yet to locate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deploy to production without downtime, Then use swap url

Docs [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)

[EDIT]
If you want to directly deployed to multiple environments by eb cli, `eb use production-env` the production db and `eb delpoy`

Please refer to docs for AWS CLI [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)

Comment: Yes I was wondering about swapping the url. That presumably assumes the same database is being used? And leaves the xxx-dev instance called xxx-dev, which might get confusing? The doc you linked to is really helpful though thanks.

Comment: Yeah, same config should be used. I have updated the answer for cli deploy

Comment: Can you expand on the 'eb use production-env' command? How do you setup the dev-env and production-env environments? It looks on the surface as this is probably what I am after. Depends though on how it affects the availability/update of the production instance.